# Derivation of the low-energy effective Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, many-body

In the quantum mechanics, the Hamiltonian $H$ satisfies the Schroedinger equation
$$
H\psi = E\psi.
$$
Suppose that $P$ is a projection operator, and $Q=1-P$. The low-energy effective Hamiltonian is
$$
H_{eff} = H_{PP} + \frac{H_{PQ}H_{QP}}{E-H_{QQ}}.
$$
My method to do so is a combination of two algebraic equations. Recently, I found a good [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0039602800004416#)(L. Petersen $et~~al.$ A simple tight-binding model of spin–orbit splitting of sp-derived surface states), whose authors declared that one can obtain (EQ. 13)
$$
P\frac{1}{\epsilon-H}P = \frac{1}{\epsilon-H_{eff}}
$$
from a standard theorem in linear algebra. Here, I just wonder that "what's the standard theorem"? Please inform me of the omited detail in the above paper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the effective Hamiltonian in a certain subspace](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/325701/)

Comment: The "standard theorem" in linear algebra is the [formula for inverting a $2\times 2$ block of matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion). See my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/345367/83545) for the detailed derivation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say the time evolution for Hamiltonian $H$ is given by $U(t) = \exp(-iHt)$ and the corresponding evolution on the support of $P$ is

$$PU(t)P = P\exp(-iHt)P = \exp(-iH_\text{eff}t) \equiv U_\text{eff}(t)$$

assuming $H_\text{eff}$ exists. The desired identity follows from

$$
\lim_{\eta \rightarrow 0} \int_0^\infty dt \; U(t) e^{i (\epsilon + i \eta) t}
= \frac{i}{\epsilon - H} \, . \tag{1}
$$

Applying $P$ to both sides of Eq. $(1)$ gives

$$
\lim_{\eta \rightarrow 0} \int_0^\infty dt \; P U(t) P e^{i (\epsilon + i \eta) t}
= P\frac{i}{\epsilon - H}P \, . \tag{2}
$$

Then using $PU(t)P = U_\text{eff}(t)$ on the left hand side of Eq. $(2)$ we get

$$
\lim_{\eta \rightarrow 0} \int_{0}^{\infty} dt \; U_\text{eff}(t) e^{ i (\epsilon + i \eta) t}
= P \frac{i}{\epsilon - H}P \, . \tag{3}
$$

Now use Eq. $(1)$ but with the effective instead of full Hamiltonian to replace the left hand side of Eq. $(3)$.
The result is

$$
\frac{1}{\epsilon - H_\text{eff}} = P\frac{1}{\epsilon - H}P
$$
as stated.

Comment: What does $\rightarrow$ mean?

Comment: Oh, should've been $\Rightarrow$ = "implies". Thanks for the fixing. However, the way you rearranged the answer might make a beginner wonder about the relation between the 1st and 2nd equalities following the integral over PU(t)P.

Comment: You're right, the way I rearranged it wasn't clear. I hope the new version is ok.

Comment: @udrv I like the argument, but it ignores the energy dependence of $H_\textrm{eff}$?